# how to make ros node to communicate through serial port?

Tags: gps, rosnode, rostopic, bagfile, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
i have bag file containing /GPSFix. i want to feed this information to gps receiver in my gis application. gis application needs port address to connect. but how can i connect bagfile node to serial port or usb? can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68512/how-to-make-ros-node-to-communicate-through-serial-port?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your GIS application is asking for a serial port, I'm assuming that it expects live GPS data in whatever raw format coming from the antenna. However, your bagfile contains data in the format that ROS uses to pass messages around, and those aren't going to be trivially compatible.

Does your GIS application have an option to load in pre-recorded data? If so, you might be able to write a simple node that subscribes to the /[GPSFix messages](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gps_common/html/msg/GPSFix.html) and outputs a properly formatted file.

Alternatively, you're probably going to be stuck writing a node that pretends to be a GPS receiver, listening to the /GPSFix messages and emitting that data as properly-formatted serial packets. I haven't done it, but [SO suggests that you can fake a serial connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500420/fake-serial-communication-under-linux).

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on 2013-07-23**:
thank u so much lindzey  for your valuable response. your answer is enough for me. My GIS application having an option to load in pre-recorded data. so i will subscribe to the /GPSFix messages . thanks.